# How to move a hook in prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I need to move my hook right between the product description and the add button to the cart, in the area I marked in the photo

[image]

So far I can only put it before and after the buttons of social networks using the admin, but I need to put my module before the button.

This is how I create my hook:

```
public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('displayProductAdditionalInfo'))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall() || !$this->unregisterHook('displayProductAdditionalInfo'))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

public function hookDisplayProductAdditionalInfo($params)
    {
        return $this->runnable();
    }
```

And this is my file that contains the iframe that I want to show

```
{block name='product_description_short' prepend}
    <style type='text/css'> 
        .products { border: none; width: 100%; height: {$height}px;  } 
    </style>
    <iframe class='products' src='{$iframe}{$token}'></iframe>
{/block}
```

How can I do to move the hook to where I need to, without having to touch the source code of the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what the concept of widget aims at. Widgets is an advanced feature introduced in PS 1.7 that extends the hooks feature.

From the [documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/widgets/):

> With widgets, module developers can display content everywhere the
>   module is asked to do so. When a module implements widgets in its
>   code, it allows:
>
> 1 a theme to call the module directly with {widget name="module_name"}
>
> 2 the core to fallback on it if a registered hook is called but its method hook() does not exist.

By following the same link you can make a module widgets compliant and then call the widget in `templates/catalog/product.tpl` in the place you want.

In classic theme for 1.7.5.0, you can call the widget in line [98](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/themes/classic/templates/catalog/product.tpl#L98) just before `<div class="product-actions">`.

Hope it helped.

**Edit**:

Let's assume your module name is 'my_module' and your custom hook name is 'myCustomHook', Here is how the module class should look like:

```
class MyModule extends Module implements WidgetInterface
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'my_module';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'me';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->description = ...
        $this->displayName = ...
        $this->confirmUninstall = ...
    }



    public function install()
    {
        if(!parent::install())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    public function uninstall()
    {
        return(parent::uninstall());
    }

    public function renderWidget($hookName = null, array $configuration = [])
    {

        $this->smarty->assign($this->getWidgetVariables($hookName, $configuration));

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/widget/my_template.tpl');

    }

    public function getWidgetVariables($hookName = null, array $configuration = [])
    {
            if($hookName === 'MyCustomHook')
            {
                $your_height_value, $your_iframe_value, $your_token_value... //  Get the values depending on your logic

                return [
                    'token' => $your_token_value;
                    'height' => $your_height_value;
                    'iframe' => $your__iframe_value;
                ];

            }
    }
```

In template file, just call the widget like:

```
{widget module='my_module' hook='myCustomHook'}
```

Comment: brother you have some example of how to do it, because I'm following the official documentation but it does not work

Comment: Thank you brother, I will wait for your help although I am still trying without success.

Comment: I Edited it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a builtin Prestashop hook and it has to stay there.

What you can do is register a custom hook of your own, like displayMyHookHere, here is a guide of how to do it [hooks in PS 1.7+](https://belvg.com/blog/custom-hooks-in-prestashop-1-7.html)

Hook your module on it and display this in any spot on your page like {hook h='displayMyHookHere'}